# How to manipulate element within html textarea tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a text inside textarea all works fine but my problem is how to access the written text so that I can change maybe their colour or background using either pure javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Is the text in the textarea HTML (like, you have a `<textarea>` and you type something like `<p>Hello</p>` so it displays that? Also, please include a code sample of what you have some people can help better.

Comment: `<textarea>` only supports plain text.

Comment: The question is pretty vague, but perhaps you're looking for something like the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute?

Comment: Yes something like this .l

Answer (score 2):

Give it an ID and then jquery

```js
$("#area").text("try").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="area">sada</textarea>
```

Comment: No I am not talking about accessing the entire text but rather each words as if I am editing a text using JavaScript .